# Ip forwarding to another subnet

Tags: 14.04, networking, juju, maas, iptables

Right now i am working on testing a MAAS setup (physical hardware). I have deployed juju and can access it within the network (10.0.3.0).

I have two interfaces eth0, internet facing, eth1 where 10.0.3.0 and the mass network is. I was able to nat the interfaces so eth 1 can access the internet via eth0 however i would like to setup some virtual interfaces (Eg. eth0:0 with a public ip)and forward it to specific webserver setup on the maas network. How can i do this?

I have already tried some basic steps to pre, and post route traffic with ip tables. I believe i am missing something to do with the subnet here. However to my knowledge i have no idea what.

```
 sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0:0 -j SNAT --to-168.XXX.XXX.72

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0:0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.12

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 168.XXX.XXX.72 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.12

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.12 -j SNAT --to-source 168.XXX.XXX.72
```

I am not very knowledgeable in this area so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

iptables does not know about interface aliasing and so you would only refer to eth0 and eth1 in any iptables rules. Assuming you have the default policy of ACCEPT for the FORWARD chain, and already have `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` set to 1, then all you should need is:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 168.XXX.XXX.72 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.3.12
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.0.3.12 -j SNAT --to-source 168.XXX.XXX.72
```